# Anyone know how to turn off will_paginate in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, spree

Deleting the lines of

```
<%  if paginated_products.is_a?(WillPaginate::Collection) 
      params.delete(:search)
      params.delete(:taxon)

%><div class="clear"></div><%= will_paginate(paginated_products, 
                    :previous_label => "&#171; #{t('previous')}", 
                    :next_label => "#{t('next')} &#187;") %>
<%  end -%>
```

Only makes it so that the pagination nav disappears but not the pagination as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hackey but you could just set the `per_page` setting to something like 1,000 so it wouldn't ever have to paginate the results.

Throwing something like this in `config/initializers/will_paginate.rb` should work.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.instance_eval do
  def per_page
    1000
  end
end
```